# is it possible to create a SQLite DB using .Net Framework/Java and Push the DB to iPhone using Web Service?

Tags: java, .net, iphone, web-services, cocoa-touch

I have created a app that will have a large set of data in the form of XML files inside documents folder. The data size is so large and its growing data by day so planning to move it to SQLLite DB. Also, i want it to be moved to SQLLite DB for security purposes. I have around 1000 XML files currently, it may grow in future. My primary issue is i want all the data inside XML files to be moved into SQLLite DB using a Backend System(.Net Framework or Java) and can i push this complete Database into the iPhone using a Web Service. So that no XML parsing happens in iPhone. Because i heard XML parsing is resource intensive than reading from SQLLite DB inside iPhone. Whether this is a feasible solution or any better approach is available?

Answer (score 0):

Don't transport the entire set of data each time. Have the iOS client request only the changes since it last synced, and have it update its local database.  Processing multiple XML documents should be fine so long as the app can synchronize in the background while the user continues to use it.

Comment: I am sending only the changes not the entire set everytime. My requirement is whether can we create a SQLLite DB using .net/java?

Comment: Chitti: there is a .NET SQLite binding, but it would not be a good idea to use it on the server; you'd be better served by a database that isn't in-process (MySQL, Postgres, SQL Server, Oracle, etc)

Comment: Joe : I mean on the server and i want to push it to iPhone